# Can we make Assignment rule criteria dynamic?

Tags: assignment-rules

In Lead assignment rule i wanted to make entry criteria 'dynamic' using custom settings or any other means.

eg. entry criteria would be if Field XYZ = 'variable value'  .This variable value should be easily modifiable so there won't be any need to change rule criteria every time.

Is it even possible?

Comment: In that case, you need to write apex code to assign ownership

Comment: can we use custom settings to store the variable value and access it in assignment rule....?

Comment: No, you have to write trigger when lead is getting created and based on the custom setting value you can assign ownership

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes, the best way to handle this is to introduce a taxonomy

Say, for example, you have assignment rules that look like this:

```
1 State equals  AZ,CA,OR,NM,NV,WA  assign to Fred
2 State equals  CO,ID,MT,UT,SD,ND  assign to Frederica
```

and you decide that Colorado (CO) is now part of the western territories covered by Fred

If your rules were instead:

```
1 Region equals West assign to Fred
2 Region equals BigSky assign to Frederica
```

then all you need to do is introduce custom field `Region__c` on your Lead and define a new mapping of Lead.State to Lead.Region__c either via formula fields or in triggers (not workflow or process builder, it is too late in the execution sequence by then). That is, remap state `CO` to region `West`

If using triggers, you can do the mapping declaratively via custom settings, custom metadata types, or custom objects.